# How to export data into csv file from multiple django models?

Tags: django

from django.db import models

Models.py

```
    class Musician(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Album(models.Model):
        artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        release_date = models.DateField()
        num_stars = models.IntegerField()

  class Runner(models.Model):
    MedalType = models.TextChoices('MedalType', 'GOLD SILVER BRONZE')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    medal = models.CharField(blank=True, choices=MedalType.choices, max_length=10)
    artist1 = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to export the data from multiple models to single csv files.Is there any way to do that ? I'm trying to applay the export features for user not on admin side.

Comment: Do you want a row per `Runner` with repeated values from the related models?

Comment: yes @ Iain Shelvington

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like this:

```
import csv

runner_fields = [x.name for x in Runner._meta.concrete_fields]
album_fields = ['artist1__{}'.format(x.name) for x in Album._meta.concrete_fields]
musician_fields = ['artist1__artist__{}'.format(x.name) for x in Musician._meta.concrete_fields]

all_fields = runner_fields + album_fields + musician_fields
runner_list = list(Runner.objects.values_list(*all_fields))

with open(..., 'w', newline='') as myfile:
     for _list in runner_list:
         wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
         wr.writerow(_list)
```

### Explanation

Here I am getting the field names from models by `_meta.concrete_fields`. Then I have added up all the model fields and passed it as argument to `Runner` model's `values_list`. It will return a list of lists. Finally, used this list of lists to write to a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a variable with the fields list. If the field is related to a foreign key, you just need to prepand "__"

Example (using your model):

```
def get_csv(request):
    # replace with the fields you need 
    fields = [
        name,
        medal,
        artist1__artist__first_name,
        artist1__name,
        artist1__release_date
    ]

    # Generate the csv file with datetime
    timestamp = datetime.now().isoformat()

    response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/csv")
    response["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename={timestamp}.csv"
    writer = csv.writer(response)

    # Write the header row
    writer.writerow(fields)

    # Use the fields to get the data, specifying the model name
    for row in Runner.objects.values(*fields):
        writer.writerow([row[field] for field in fields])
    # return
    return response
```